# List item default value based on another item in the same list + value

Tags: list, calculated-column

How do I set the default value of a list item to be based on another item's value + value? 
For example:

`List A`: `duedate`, `reminderdate`

once the user enters a value in the list-->
`duedate` = `1/1/2016`

then it automatically updates this value -->
`reminderdate` = `1/1/2016` + `4 months`

I'm thinking of using workflows but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a calculation for this. Create the column `reminderdate` as a calculated column of the *Date and Time* type.

Then use the following calculation: `=DATE(YEAR([dueDate]),MONTH([dueDate])+4,DAY([dueDate]))`

If you are using another regional language than english, you may have to replace all commas (,) with a (;).

Every time the column `dueDate`gets a new value, the calculation in the `reminderdate` will get updated.

The result will looks like this.

[image]

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx)